# My code passes all my tests but some how edabit is not approving it

Tags: javascript, bitwise-operators, bitwise-and, bitwise-xor, bitwise-or

```
function bitwiseAND(n1, n2) {
  let a = n1.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
  let b = n2.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
  let x = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
     if (+a[i] === 1 && +a[i] === +b[i]) x = x + "1";
     else x = x + "0";
}
return +x
}

function bitwiseOR(n1, n2) {
  let a = n1.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
  let b = n2.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
  let x = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if (+a[i] === 1 || +b[i] === 1) x = x + "1";
    else x = x + "0";
}
return +x
}

function bitwiseXOR(n1, n2) {
  let a = n1.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
  let b = n2.toString(2).padStart(8, "0");
  let x = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    if ((+a[i] === 1 && +b[i] === 0) || (+a[i] === 0 && +b[i] === 1))
      x = x + "1";
    else x = x + "0";
}
return +x
}
```

[This is link to the challenge](https://edabit.com/challenge/vvuAkYEAArrZvmp6X)

challenge was to Write three functions to calculate the bitwise AND, bitwise OR and bitwise XOR of two numbers.

Comment: run `console.log(bitwiseAND(7,12))` and inspect the result. I somehow doubt it's `4` as expected in the example but I suspect it will be `100`

Comment: The challenge has a foot note that mentions toString, but it does not say that you must use it.

Comment: @pytness what's the point of your comment?

Comment: @derpirscher im just pointing a tip that, by the looks of the challenge and its comments, its easily missed by many people.

Comment: @pytness if you carefully look at OP's code, you will notice he *is indeed* using the mentioned `toString(2)`

Comment: @derpirscher im talking about the opposite. While the challenge mentions `toString` (and OP's code is a valid solution of the challenge), I believe it is meant as a debugging tip as the challenge has the labels such as `bit_operations` and `language_fundamentals`. I was pointing to the more obvious answer of using bitwise operators, which fair enough, might out of the scope of this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is good, the only thing that is missing is to convert the binary to an integer on your return values.

Insted of

```
return +x
```

Try

```
return parseInt(x, 2)
```